# how the node size parameter is implemented on the Leiden algorithm

Tags: python, graph, graph-theory

I’m working on Leiden community detection algorithm (LeidenAlg Python library) with different quality functions that fit directed networks. Also, I’m discovering different parameter effects on results; Specifically the “node_size” one. I do see significant impact on the results when changing “node_sizes” parameter. For example, using the strength (weighted degree) as “node_sizes” gives worse results than using the degree as “node_sizes”.

I’m trying to find how “node_sizes” is implemented on the Leiden algorithm. Also, I have tried digging into the algorithm codes, but couldn’t find an answer as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please allow me to tell that this is problem is more to know how a parameter works rather that how to use it.